# Can I install JupyterHub on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: jupyterhub, ubuntu-20.04

I would like to install JupyterHub on a server running Ubuntu 20.04. Is this possible? The documentation for TLJH, for example, explicitly states that the tool is supported for Ubuntu 18.04.

Any comment is much appreciated.

Thanks!